# Why overloading "<<" needs a const argument?

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class complex
{
 [...]
 complex operator+(const complex &c) const;
 [...]
 friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const complex &c);
};
```

```
complex complex::operator+(const complex &c) const
{
 complex result;
 result.real_m = real_m + c.real_m;
 result.imaginary_m = imaginary_m + c.imaginary_m;
 return result;
}
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const complex &c)
{
 os << "(" << c.real_m << "," << c.imaginary_m << "i)";
 return os;
}
```

```
int main()
{
  complex a(3.0, 4.0);
  complex c(5.0, 8.0);
  cout << "a is " << a << '\n';
  cout << "a + c is " << a + c << '\n';
  [...]
 }
```

and, everything works fine, but if i remove `const` in `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const complex &c)` the `cout << "a is " << a << '\n';` works fine but `cout << "a + c is " << a + c << '\n';` doesn't, it say: No operator "<<" matches these operands. Thus, why this doesn't work without const ?

Comment: To add to the dupe: `a + c` creates a temporary object.

Comment: `a + c` is an rvalue, It can be passed as a const reference, or by copy or rvalue reference, but not as a non-const reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a + c` is not an l-value,  and so you cannot use a non-const reference on it.

Comment: a non-const reference. You can get a const reference, though

Comment: An important insight here is that this does **not** depend on `<<` being an overloaded operator. **Any function** has the same behavior.